# How to extend My custom library to my controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, extending

I want my `Custom_library` class extend to `My_custom_controller`. Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of extending , you can load library in controller constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend simply extend:

```
class xyz extends utv
{
    //class code here
}
```

But I advise you to load library in constructor to private $var in your controller

```
class My_custom_controller
{
    private $libs;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->libs = new Custom_library();
    }
}
```

I advise you that becouse you really don't want to extend library in controller, you can override something by accident, that way you will have access to library and you will be shure that nothing wrong goes with your library

Comment: This is general OOPS concept. CI handle this differently.